# How can I force a flex column to use all available width?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have the following markup which has a spacer col so i can left align and then right align. It looks great on a laptop screen. However on a larger monitor the spacer doesn't stretch to use all the available space. The input box and the button align nicely together on the laptop screen but there is a large space on the monitor.

How can i achieve keeping the button and input box together and get the spacer to use all the available space?

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <div fxFlex="15">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Acciones Multiples">
                <mat-option [value]=""></mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Delete">Eliminar</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="15">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Aplicar</button>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex></div>
    <div fxFlex="8">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Estado" (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value)">
                <mat-option [value]="">Todas</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="16">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Buscador por nombre o CIF">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should tag the layout library you're using.

Comment: Flex items self-align accordingly to each other. If you want one item to take the 100% of the width, then it's enough that other items have 0%. So just set "flex: 1" to it

Comment: You may want `flexFill`. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexFill-API

Comment: fxFlexFill doesn't work. It takes up all the space to the right and the matInput  completely disappears

Answer (score 0):

Cristian Traìna put me on the right path. I removed all the fxflex values from all except the spacer which i set to 100. Setting it to 1 wasn't enough. I then had to add a bit of padding inbetween elements as space-between wouldn't work.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <div class="pr-4">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Acciones Multiples">
                    <mat-option [value]=""></mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="Delete">Eliminar</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Aplicar</button>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="100"></div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Estado" (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value)">
                    <mat-option [value]="">Todas</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="Active">Activas</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="Inactive">Inactivas</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="pl-4">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Buscador por nombre o CIF">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
```